Romantic comedy with "overweight unattractive" woman
A few years ago, I watched a movie. I was younger, and have no idea if I'd like it now, but remember liking it then.
I remember a few scenes of the movie; Starts off with "overweight unattractive" woman and some guy who im assuming is famous is looking for a girlfriend (i believe). So she goes to an auto shop and they somehow make her lose weight and more attractive and de-hair her by the time she leaves the auto shop. She goes to the guy's house and it's narrowed down to her and a few other woman. He shoots all the other woman except her. She meets his ex-girlfriend, basically a sex god, while she washes a car in a bikini with Don't Cha by the Pussycat Dolls playing in the background.
The middle of the movie is a blur, but they somehow have a fallout and breakup, she's upset and eating a tv dinner, he shows up outside her window blaring music from a boombox telling her he wants her back.
Pretty sure it's a romantic comedy. What movie is this?

Your question reminded me of Shallow Hal although it's certainly not it :)

+1 for adding details to your question. I was able to find the movie by the song you mentioned.

It sounds like it should be the Alyson Hannigan (2006) movie: Date Movie. 
I looked at "other uses in media" section of the song's wikipedia page.

Plot description from Wikipedia:
Julia Jones (Alyson Hannigan) is an obese woman, who dreams of marrying Napoleon Dynamite (Josh Meyers), but even in her dreams she is rejected. Writing in her diary, she thinks she will never find her true love. Julia goes outside and dances to impress men on the streets, but is unsuccessful. Julia goes to work at her father Frank's (Eddie Griffin) Greek diner. There she meets Grant Fockyerdoder, with whom she forms an instant attraction. When Frank yells at Julia to get an order, she turns to respond and hits Grant over the head with the coffee pot she is holding, knocking him to the floor. She turns around only to find his table is suddenly empty and figures he ran away. Julia wants help and goes to see a love therapist, Hitch, who rejects her at first but reluctantly agrees to help her. Hitch takes her to a garage where she gets "pimped out" and made slimmer.
